# Is there a form to resize an image and mask for image segmentation?

Tags: python, memory, image-segmentation

I'm trying the Meta Segment Anything model for a small personal project. However, when I attempt automatic segmentation or any other operation, I run into GPU memory issues due to the large image resolution. I need to be able to segment images at their original resolution.

To address this, I resized the original image to reduce memory usage during the process, using the resize function of cv2, which did work. However, I now face an issue where the segmented image doesn't align properly with the original image when I try to display both, resulting in a program crash.

This step is crucial for me because it enables me to segment any image, regardless of its size. The image I'm trying to segment is in 4K resolution, and it works well with smaller images, such as those in 1920 resolution. I've already tried Google Colab, but the problem persists, and I prefer to make it work locally by scaling the image resolution within the code, rather than relying on other programs to resize all the images.

```
import os
import torch
import cv2
import supervision as sv

HOME = os.getcwd()
print("HOME:", HOME)

CHECKPOINT_PATH = os.path.join(HOME, "weights", "sam_vit_h_4b8939.pth")
print(CHECKPOINT_PATH, "; exist:", os.path.isfile(CHECKPOINT_PATH))

DEVICE = torch.device('cuda:0' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
MODEL_TYPE = "vit_h"

from segment_anything import sam_model_registry, SamAutomaticMaskGenerator, SamPredictor

sam = sam_model_registry[MODEL_TYPE](checkpoint=CHECKPOINT_PATH).to(device=DEVICE)

mask_generator = SamAutomaticMaskGenerator(sam)

IMAGE_NAME = "prueba2.jpg"
IMAGE_PATH = os.path.join(HOME, "data", IMAGE_NAME)

image_bgr = cv2.imread(IMAGE_PATH)
image_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image_bgr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
#in this line i resize the image
image_rgb = cv2.resize(image_rgb, (1920, 1080))

sam_result = mask_generator.generate(image_rgb)

print(sam_result[0].keys())


#in this part of the code the image should be displayed with the original and the segmented one
mask_annotator = sv.MaskAnnotator()

detections = sv.Detections.from_sam(sam_result=sam_result)

annotated_image = mask_annotator.annotate(scene=image_bgr.copy(), detections=detections)

sv.plot_images_grid(
    images=[image_bgr, annotated_image],
    grid_size=(1, 2),
    titles=['source image', 'segmented image']
)
```

Comment: Have you tried resizing the mask to the original image's resolution after generation?

Comment: I hadn't thought about that; I'll try it. but how? its suposed that every image can have diferent resolutions